# Find business reviews using yelp API

Tags: api, yelp

I am using Yelp API for searching business reviews.

[http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=fire-it-up-naperville&location=Naperville, IL 60563&ywsid=xxxxxxxxxxxx](http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=fire-it-up-naperville&location=Naperville,%20IL%2060563&ywsid=xxxxxxxxxxxx)

we get only 20 reviews at a time. But i want to get next page reviews. there is no input parameter for getting next page reviews. Is there any way to get next page reviews via Ylp API.

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the business_review_search endpoint isn't part of the Yelp API 2.0.
The available endpoints are described [here](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business).

For your request, maybe you should try to add an offset parameter with offset=20 to get the next 20 reviews.